# Model returning null from a View with multiple models

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two models, LoginModel and DatabaseModel. Combining them, I have created DatabaseCombinedWithOtherModel. The View, Login.cshtml is Strongly-Typed with the combined model. On running the Login.cshtml, the LoginModel returns null

I have all the necessary get and set methods

Here is the Controller class

```
namespace ReadingCat.Controllers
{
  public class LoginController : Controller
  {

      private int userid;
      // GET: Login
      [HttpGet]
      public ActionResult Login()
      {
          return View(new DatabaseCombinedWithOtherModel());
      }
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Login(DatabaseCombinedWithOtherModel model)
      {
          string realPassword = "";
          string paswordFromUser = "";


        string query = "SELECT password, userid FROM USERS WHERE username 
       = '" + model.loginModel.username + "'";
        DataSet dataSet = model.databaseModel.selectFunction(query);
        if (realPassword == paswordFromUser)
        {
            userid = 
       Convert.ToInt32(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1]);
            model.loginModel.userid = userid;
            return View("~/Views/Profile/Profile.cshtml", 
     model.loginModel);
        }
        else
            return View();
    }

    }
}
```

Here is the Model:

```
namespace ReadingCat.Models
{
public class DatabaseCombinedWithOtherModel
{
   public DatabaseModel databaseModel { get; set; }
    public LoginModel loginModel { get; set; }
}
}
```

And here is the View:

```
  @model ReadingCat.Models.DatabaseCombinedWithOtherModel

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <title>Login</title>
 <!-- Main css -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/login.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
        <form class="register-form">
        </form>
          @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
        {
    <form class="login-form">
        @Html.TextBox("Username", null, new { placeholder = "Username", 
  @class = "login.css" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.loginModel.username);
       @Html.Password("Password", null, new { placeholder = "Password", 
  @class = "login.css" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.loginModel.password);
        <div class="form-submit">
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" 
   id="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
        <p class="message">Not registered? <a 
 href="http://localhost:64907/Register/Register">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
        }
    </div>
</div>

    <img class="coffee-image" src="~/images/coffee.gif" alt="">
```

It is giving the following error

```
  System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance 
  of 
  an object.'

ReadingCat.Models.DatabaseCombinedWithOtherModel.loginModel.get returned 
null.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error about not fully declare `DatabaseCombinedWithOtherModel`this model.
Please try this code.

```
    private int userid
    DatabaseCombinedWithOtherModel modelobj = new DatabaseCombinedWithOtherModel();
   // GET: Login
   [HttpGet]
          public ActionResult Login()
          {
              return View(modelobj);
          }
```

> And also try this thing that before call the model in view firstly add some
>   values in objects from controller side pass   `return View(modelobj);`and then call in view side.

Comment: I have posted how I solved this problem below, It is pretty much similar to what you have posted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not seting the loginmodel, it will be null Which will throw the exception.

Either initialize the loginModel in the otherModel's constructor or in the Login get action.
Try

```
 namespace ReadingCat.Models
 {
    public class DatabaseCombinedWithOtherModel
    {
       public DatabaseModel databaseModel { get; set; }
        public LoginModel loginModel { get; set; }
    }
    public DatabaseCombinedWithOtherModel()
    {
      loginModel  = new LoginModel();
      databaseModel = new DatabaseModel();
    }
  }
```

or

```
      [HttpGet]
      public ActionResult Login()
      {
          var vm = new DatabaseCombinedWithOtherModel()
          vm.loginModel = new LoginModel();
          vm.databaseModel = new DatabaseModel();
          return View(vm);
      }
```

Comment: yes I have already done something similar to this and it's working. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned error goes away if @Html.Textbox is replaced with @Html.EditorFor. Then, another error arises with the DatabaseModel. It returns null. So I created a different object of DatabaseModel and worked with that.